# Way to force specific column down to next row in smaller sizes?

Tags: zurb-foundation

Say I have three columns:

Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3

And I would like, when the screen size changes to "small", the columns to change to this:

Col 1 | Col 3

Col 2 (in it's own full-size row)

Basically, Col 3 would go onto it's own row. Now, I know I can do this with the "visiblity" classes Foundation provides, but then you'd have to duplicate the Col 2 content twice, as far as I understand it. I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Any ideas? Or am I crazy that Foundation doesn't easily allow for this? Or maybe I should just hack it together by making Col 2  `positive: absolute` or something and call it a day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something called [Source Ordering](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html). (It's towards the bottom of that docs page.)

Order your html so that the columns are defined in the order 1,3,2.  Then, use the push/pull classes to swap the positions of columns 3 and 2 for when they are all in the same row.

```
<div class="small-6 medium-4 columns">
  ... Column 1 Content ...
</div>

<div class="small-6 medium-4 columns medium-push-4">
  ... Column 3 Content ...
</div>

<div class="small-12 medium-4 columns medium-pull-4">
  ... Column 2 Content ...
</div>
```